# QtCreator CMake and GCOV

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, gcov

I have a simple project in Qt Creator where i run tests with GoogleTest and when I run them I want to generate a code coverage html from the file in `src`. But it only generates .gcda files for the `test` directory and no html file.

This is my project structure:

```
 Calculator
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ Calculator.cpp
 ┃ ┣ Calculator.h
 ┃ ┣ CMakeLists.txt
 ┃ ┗ main.cpp
 ┣ test
 ┃ ┣ CMakeLists.txt
 ┃ ┣ main.cpp
 ┃ ┗ Calculator-test.cpp
 ┣ CMakeLists.txt
 ┗ CodeCoverage.cmake
```

The `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(Calculator LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})
add_executable(${BINARY} ${SOURCES})
add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
message(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

The `test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_test)
file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES false *.h *.cpp)
set(SOURCES ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_executable(${BINARY} ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})
target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
include(CodeCoverage)
append_coverage_compiler_flags()
setup_target_for_coverage_gcovr_html(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage EXECUTABLE ${PROJECT_NAME} DEPENDENCIES ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

The `CodeCoverage.cmake` is from here: https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake

Btw: I run Linux and gcov is installed. GCC is version 11.1.0

As requested here the output of `cmake --build build-Desktop-Debug --verbose`:

```
[1/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/Calculator.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/Calculator.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/Calculator.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/src/Calculator.cpp
[2/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/Calculator.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/Calculator.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/Calculator.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/src/Calculator.cpp
[3/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/main.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/src/main.cpp
[4/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/main.cpp.o -MF src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/src/main.cpp
[5/9] : && /usr/bin/g++ -g  src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/Calculator.cpp.o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator.dir/main.cpp.o -o src/Calculator   && :
[6/9] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f src/libCalculator_lib.a && /usr/bin/ar qc src/libCalculator_lib.a  src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/Calculator.cpp.o src/CMakeFiles/Calculator_lib.dir/main.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib src/libCalculator_lib.a && :
[7/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fprofile-abs-path -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/test/main.cpp
[8/9] /usr/bin/g++  -I/home/user/Develop/Calculator/src -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fprofile-abs-path -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/MyClass-test.cpp.o -MF test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/MyClass-test.cpp.o.d -o test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/MyClass-test.cpp.o -c /home/user/Develop/Calculator/test/MyClass-test.cpp
[9/9] : && /usr/bin/g++ -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fprofile-abs-path -g  test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/MyClass-test.cpp.o test/CMakeFiles/Calculator_test.dir/main.cpp.o -o test/Calculator_test  src/libCalculator_lib.a  -lgtest && :
```

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? Can you show the build commands CMake runs? Try `cmake --build build_dir --verbose`.

Comment: Also, CMake 3.5 does not support C++20; support was introduced in 3.12. So you _must_ raise your minimum version to at least that. In fact, you should raise it to no lower than the version you're _actually_ using to test your build.